# Getting values from a DateTimePicker in Form and add them to a text box in a RDLC Report

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a Form with a 2 DateTimePickers and a Button. When the Button clicked, another Form with Report Viewer will open. RDLC report attached to that Report Viewer has 2 text boxes to show date values selected in DateTimePickers. But I couldn't find a way to add those values to RDLC report. Please help me on this.

Form 1:

```
private void btnGenerate_expense_report_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime sDate = dPStartDate_expense_report.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        DateTime eDate = dPEndDate_expense_report.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        var repExpense = new ReportExpenses(sDate, eDate);
        repExpense.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with below

```
    DateTime sDate = dPStartDate_expense_report.Value;
    DateTime eDate = dPEndDate_expense_report.Value;
```

`.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` will convert `datetime` to a `string`, you don't need to convert `DateTimePicker` value to string if the `ReportExpenses` constructor accept `datetime` values

Or you can directly use the value

```
var repExpense = new ReportExpenses(dPStartDate_expense_report.Value, dPEndDate_expense_report.Value);
```

Now you can set the parameter values for the report viewer

```
ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("sDate", sDate);
ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("eDate", eDate);
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[]{p1,p2});
```

Assume you already added two parameters with name `"sDate" and "eDate"` having type of `DateTime` in your report

If you need to set the textbox text using above parameter value, you can add expression as

`=Parameters!sDate.Value`